# C# System.Double& to System.Double

Tags: c#, reference, out, gettype

I have Type variable t with value representing reference e.g. System.Double& or System.Double[]&, ...
Now I would like to create an instance of object with type System.Double or System.Double[], ...

Question edit:

```
        Type t = param.ParameterType;
        if (t == Type.GetType("System.String&"))
            return Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType("System.String"), new object[] { new char[] { ' ' } });
        if (t == Type.GetType("System.Double[]&"))
            return Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType("System.Dobule[]"), new object[] { 10 }); // throw Error !!!!
        else
            return Activator.CreateInstance(t.GetElementType());
```

Edit 2:
I would like to implement something like this:

```
Type t = param.ParameterType;
if t is a reference to an array of any dimensions -> create its instance
if t is a ref to string -> create its instance
if t is a ref to any other data types -> create its instance
```

Comment: What is `System.Double&` and `System.Double&&`? o.O

Comment: Are you sure you are talking about C#?

Comment: Can you elaborate more on this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ampersand `&` probably comes from the CLR name of the type. It indicates that it is a `ByRef` version of the type. Did you get the `Type` with reflection from a method parameter decorated with the `ref` or `out` keyword?

Example:

```
var t1 = typeof(double);
Console.WriteLine(t1);        // "System.Double"
var t2 = t1.MakeByRefType();
Console.WriteLine(t2);        // "System.Double&"
var t3 = t2.GetElementType();
Console.WriteLine(t3);        // "System.Double"

Console.WriteLine(t1 == t3);  // "True"
```

For an example with the `ref` keyword, suppose you have a method (inside a type `Program`) that looks like this:

```
public static bool TestMethod(ref double d)
{
  return true;
}
```

Then you can do:

```
var t4 = typeof(Program).GetMethod("TestMethod").GetParameters()[0].ParameterType;
Console.WriteLine(t4);        // "System.Double&"
```

Again, you can remove the `&` with `GetElementType()`.

The same with the array type, it can also be `ByRef` or not.

---

**Additions after edits:**

Instead of e.g. `Type.GetType("System.String[]")` I strongly suggest you use `typeof(string[])`. It is much safer to use the C# keyword `typeof`.

If you want to get rid of any "trailing ampersand", that is if you want to remove "ByRef" when present, you can say:

```
Type t = param.ParameterType;
if (t.IsByRef)
    t = t.GetElementType();
```

Finally, the reason why you get a run-time exception seems to be a misspelling of `Dobule`.
Wouldn't have happened with `typeof(double)` (spelling would be checked at compile-time).

And it is much, much easier to say:

```
return " ";
```

instead of your:

```
return Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType("System.String"), new object[] { new char[] { ' ' } });
```

and to say:

```
return new double[10];
```

instead of your:

```
return Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType("System.Double[]"), new object[] { 10 }); // spelling error fixed
```

Why make everything so indirect?

Comment: Thank you Jeppe. It really works. Nevertheless I have problem to create an instance for e.g. System.Double[]&. I tried to solve it as well as for System.String& but it does not work. See the code snippet I added to the origin question.

Comment: @charlie87 Extended my "answer".

Comment: Thank you again Jeppe. It works and helps me to understand. The reason I used the Activator.CreatInstance was that I wanted to implement it in general which is not possible due to nonparameterless constructors for array. Would it be possible to implement an general code for any type array ??? see the edit

Comment: @charlie87 You would use [`Array.CreateInstance` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.createinstance.aspx).